# What is it the estimate of Moore's law, a program to do this

Tags: java, c++, c

In 1988, the number of transistors in the Intel 386 SX microprocessor was 275,000. What were the transistor counts of the Pentium II  Intel microprocessor in 1997?

If Intel doubles the number of transistors every two years, the new processor would have

```
Pn = 275,000 * 2^n (where n = 9/2 = 4.5)    
   = 275,000 * 22.63
   = 6.2 million transistors
```

So How would be a code for this using C, C++ or java...

Comment: This is actually a common miss quote.

Comment: <quote>The complexity for minimum component costs has increased at a rate of roughly a factor of two per year... Certainly over the short term this rate can be expected to continue, if not to increase. Over the longer term, the rate of increase is a bit more uncertain, although there is no reason to believe it will not remain nearly constant for at least 10 years. That means by 1975, the number of components per integrated circuit for minimum cost will be 65,000. I believe that such a large circuit can be built on a single wafer.</quote>

Comment: @Martin you should continue reading. Moore changed his projection to double transistors every 2 years in 1975: "Most notably, in 1975, Moore altered his projection to a doubling every two years."

Comment: @eznme: You should re-read the quote. Its about **cost** not packing density. It has been shortened and misquoted to be about packing density.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define BASELINE_CPU_YEAR 1988
#define BASELINE_CPU_TRANSISTORS 275000

/* Estimate transistor count for Intel CPUs for a given year
 * based on Moore's law */
double moores_law(int year) {
        float year_offset = (year - BASELINE_CPU_YEAR) / 2.0;
        return BASELINE_CPU_TRANSISTORS * pow(2, year_offset);
}

int main () {
        int year = 1997;
        printf("Moore's law projects a %d CPU would have %.2f transistors.\n", 
                year, moores_law(year));

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed. Moore changed his projection in 1975 to doubling the number of transistors every *two* years.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {
    double transistors = 275000;
    double years = 1997-1988;
    printf("%f", transistors*pow(2.0,years/2)); // 6222539.674442
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In java or c# you can do something like this

```
int year = 2010; //for example

double  P0 = 275000;
float n = ((float)year - 1988) / 2; //1988 -> base year

double Pn = P0 * (Math.Pow(2, n));
```

Comment: Wouldn't `float n = (year - 1998) / 2;` evaluate to 4, rather than 4.5?